# How to read in all the images in a file and output them as image form on the website?

Tags: php, html

So in my folder (x), there is the HTML file and another folder (y) for my images. I want to read in all images in folder y and output them as `<img>` form on my HTML page. I've looked up php and javascript, trying to make them work, but haven't had good luck. Can someone help me out?

Assume all images in folder y are in .jpg form.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of getting a directory listing for all files that match a wildcard. In your case, `*.jpg`.
You can use the `glob` function for this, followed by a forEach loop to step through the list of matching filenames.

```
<?php
// Creates a page full of jpg images found in the specified directory (current one if none specified)
function showFiles($findMe)
{
    foreach (glob($findMe) as $filename) 
            echo "<img src='$filename'/>";
}
showFiles("*.jpg");
?>
```